# Wait for service to gracefully exit before machine shutdown/reboot

Tags: systemd

How do you write a systemd service that gracefully shuts down upon machine shutdown or reboot? In particular, it should delay machine shutdown until it exits gracefully.

I have a service that takes 10 seconds to shut down: /usr/local/bin/shutdowntest.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

SHUTDOWN=0
SHUTDOWN_TIME=10
TRAPPED_SIGNAL=

function onexit() {
  TRAPPED_SIGNAL=$1
  SHUTDOWN=1
}

for SIGNAL in SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP SIGPIPE SIGALRM SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2; do
  trap "onexit $SIGNAL" $SIGNAL
done

echo >&2 "shutdowntest running"
while ((!SHUTDOWN || SHUTDOWN_TIME>0)); do
  if [[ -n "$TRAPPED_SIGNAL" ]]; then
    echo >&2 "shutdowntest received signal $TRAPPED_SIGNAL"
    TRAPPED_SIGNAL=
  elif ((SHUTDOWN)); then
    echo >&2 "shutdowntest Shutting down: $SHUTDOWN_TIME more sleeps"
    SHUTDOWN_TIME=$((SHUTDOWN_TIME-1))
    sleep 1
  else
    sleep 10
  fi
done
echo >&2 "shutdowntest Finished shutting down; quitting"
```

I set TimeoutStopSec to 15s in /etc/systemd/system/shutdowntest.service:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/shutdowntest.sh
TimeoutStopSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `sudo systemctl stop shutdowntest.service`, the service shuts down gracefully according to `/var/log/syslog`:

```
00:57:11 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest received signal SIGTERM
00:57:11 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 10 more sleeps
00:57:11 systemd[1]: Stopping shutdowntest.service...
00:57:11 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: Terminated
00:57:11 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 9 more sleeps
00:57:12 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 8 more sleeps
00:57:13 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 7 more sleeps
00:57:14 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 6 more sleeps
00:57:15 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 5 more sleeps
00:57:16 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 4 more sleeps
00:57:17 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 3 more sleeps
00:57:18 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 2 more sleeps
00:57:19 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 1 more sleeps
00:57:20 shutdowntest.sh[1980]: shutdowntest Finished shutting down; quitting
00:57:20 systemd[1]: Stopped shutdowntest.service.
```

But when I `sudo reboot` or `sudo shutdown now` the machine, the service is killed without enough time to exit gracefully, and the /var/log/syslog ends only 1s later.

```
00:59:30 shutdowntest.sh[2014]: Terminated
00:59:30 shutdowntest.sh[2014]: shutdowntest received signal SIGTERM
00:59:30 shutdowntest.sh[2014]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 10 more sleeps
00:59:30 systemd[1]: Stopping shutdowntest.service...
```

How to ensure that the service is given the time (`TimeoutSec` or `TimeoutStopSec`) to exit when the machine is shutdown or rebooted?

Comment: systemd should already wait for the service to be stopped. Can you check with in the journal (`journalctl -u shutdowntest.service`) instead of looking directly in `/var/log/syslog`? I'm wondering if syslog is not stopped before your service and then not logging the rest of the output

Answer (score 8):

The [comment from Bigon](https://serverfault.com/questions/904346/wait-for-service-to-gracefully-exit-before-machine-shutdown-reboot#comment1169820_904346) is correct. I was looking in `/var/log/syslog`, but this is written by `rsyslog.service`, which systemd stops pretty early in the shutdown process (as indicated by “Stopped System Logging Service” below).

After I enabled persistent journald logging instead (`Storage=persistent` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and `systemctl restart systemd-journald`), `journalctl -b-1 -u shutdowntest.service` shows that my service is indeed given enough time to shut down after the system is `reboot`ed, `shutdown`, or after the Power key is pressed (ACPI G2 Soft Off).

```
journalctl -b-1 -u shutdowntest.service -u rsyslog.service -u systemd-logind
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-03-26 18:39:12 UTC, end at Mon 2018-03-26 20:22:34 UTC. --
…
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost systemd-logind[1202]: Power key pressed.
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost systemd-logind[1202]: Powering Off...
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost systemd-logind[1202]: System is powering down.
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: Terminated
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest received signal SIGTERM
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 10 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost systemd[1]: Stopping shutdowntest.service...
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Mar 26 18:46:46 myhost systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
Mar 26 18:46:47 myhost systemd[1]: Stopped System Logging Service.
Mar 26 18:46:47 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 9 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:48 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 8 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:49 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 7 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:50 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 6 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:51 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 5 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:52 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 4 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:53 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 3 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:54 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 2 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:55 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Shutting down: 1 more sleeps
Mar 26 18:46:56 myhost shutdowntest.sh[1237]: shutdowntest Finished shutting down; quitting
Mar 26 18:46:56 myhost systemd[1]: Stopped shutdowntest.service.
```